# ACRA not catching exception in background service

Tags: service, exception, background, acra

I'm using ACRA in my application and can happily catch deliberately thrown exceptions in the UI code.

However if I throw the same type of exception in my background service ACRA does not catch and report the exception.

Should I expect ACRA to catch exceptions in a background service? If so do I need to do any additional configuration beyond the following which is in my application class attachBaseCOntext() method

```
CoreConfigurationBuilder builder = new CoreConfigurationBuilder(this);
builder.setBuildConfigClass(BuildConfig.class).setReportFormat(StringFormat.JSON);
builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(MailSenderConfigurationBuilder.class).setEnabled(true).setMailTo("kevin@electricpocket.com").setReportAsFile(true);
builder.getPluginConfigurationBuilder(ToastConfigurationBuilder.class).setEnabled(true).setResText(R.string.acra_toast_text);
ACRA.init(this, builder);
```

Answer (score 0):

ACRA will only catch exceptions for the thread in which it is initialized.

I suspect your background service is running in another thread, and hence needs to initialize ACRA itself.